# how to handle the error: "Arguments must be separated by a comma" in Symfony?

Tags: html, symfony, variables, error-handling, twig

This is my code (html\twig):

```
{% for h in logo %}
    <img id="profile" style="width:200px;height:180px" src="{{asset('uploads/picturesgroupe/{{ h['logoname']}}')}}">
{% endfor %}
```

I got this error message in Symfony2: Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "logoname" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in IkprojGroupeBundle:Groupe:calandar1.html.twig at line 332

Please focus on the Twig variable: `{{ h['logoname']}}` .

My question is: how can I handle that error and what is the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the right [concatenate operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{% for h in logo %}
    <img id="profile" style="width:200px;height:180px" src="{{asset('uploads/picturesgroupe/' ~ h['logoname'])}}">
{% endfor %}
```

If you prefer to do [string interpolation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation), you should use:

```
{% for h in logo %}
    <img id="profile" style="width:200px;height:180px" src="{{asset('uploads/picturesgroupe/#{h.logoname}')}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well, I tried the first code you gave me but it didn't work (it didn't show any image in my page after running the code). Then, I tried your second code and it didn't work as well, Symfony shows me this error message: Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "logoname" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in IkprojGroupeBundle:Groupe:calandar1.html.twig at line 334 .... I guess that the problem comes from the two quotes surrounding logoname in `h['logoname']`, don't you agree with me??

Comment: Yep, you can replace `h['logname']` by `h.logname`, i'm editing. If there is a problem with the first method, can you please check what is generated inside your `src=""`? I guess this might help finding why the asset is not found.

Comment: finally it worked!!...I tried this line: `<img id="profile" style="width:200px;height:180px" src="{{asset(h.logoname)}}">`. Thanks a lot for your help my friend...merci beaucoup mon ami :)